# Installing rpm packages in manjaro

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro

I have installed manjaro distro on my computer but I'm unable to install any .rpm packages and from my  researches you can only install packages using pacman and AUR.What I'm asking is that is there any way to install rpm packages on manjaro considering it is derived from Arch linux?

Answer (score 2):

It is in the AUR depository. Download the Arch Linux package `yay`, then, **not as root**, use `yay` rather than `pacman`, and run

```
yay google-chrome
```

then type "1" when that option appears, and you'll have it. I just installed it this week on Arch.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.
Arch (and any based ditros on it) does not rely on `RPM` **[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager)]** format, that's is in fact developed and used by Red Hat derivates.

There are some cases (e.g. this one **[[2](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/firefox-kde-opensuse-rpm/)]**) in which a RPM package is used to install an application on Arch (and derivates) systems, but prior to do this, the RPM is extracted and handled/converted in the Arch flavour.

---

Comment: So there aren't any package for arch systems like .deb or rpm for offline installiation?Then how would you go about installing google chrome for example which is not the official repository or any other programm for that matter?I have installed the  rpm app through pacman but you have to install every single dependencies yourself which is very inconvinient compared to what I'm used to in debian based systemes.I used to be have fedora and was quite easy to use. Isn't it possible to just install the required packegs used in redhat systems in manjaro ?Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Sure, pacman standard package format is `.pkg.tar.zst`, in fact you can install any package from official repositories by downloading the package e.g. for gedit app [https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gedit/download/]. Anyway, it looks like you are a bit confused, so I suggest you *in primis* to give a read of the ArchLinux wiki, starting from FAQ [https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions]